# What is the total memory overhead of creating a single byte in python?

Tags: python

When I run the following code in Python:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> mybyte = bytes(1)
>>> sys.getsizeof(mybyte)
34
```

I'd ideally expect something around 1 as size because I created a variable to store a single byte, that I don't want to be a string necessarily. I'd like to understand why it's returning a size of 34 bytes.

What are all data structures adding overhead to this single byte definition?

Comment: Because you don't have a single byte, you have _a bytes object_.

Comment: If it was just a single byte, you couldn't use any of the methods the `bytes` class provides, like `mybyte.hex()`. You're not in fact measuring the size of a byte, you're measuring the size of a Python `bytes` instance.

Comment: The struct for a `bytes` instance in CPython is a `PyBytesObject`, defined in [Lib/bytesobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Include/cpython/bytesobject.h#L5-L15).

Comment: @wim But the instance has to hold a reference to its class, no?

Comment: @wim Of course they are, but if `mybyte` was just a single plain byte, then it wouldn't even have a reference to the class!

Comment: Yes, and overhead is due to the references, hash, etc.. but it matters nothing to the size of an instance how many methods the type has

Comment: @wim Not that I ever said that.

Comment: So I guess in this case is 8 bytes reference, 8 bytes for size, 8 bytes for hash cache, 8 bytes GC overhead (refcount), and 2 bytes for the char array itself.

Comment: @wim thanks for the better response, if you can format it properly I can accept it as the correct answer.